# Pytest ImportError and ModuleNotFoundError when running test from a sub directory

Tags: python, mysql, pytest, importerror, conftest

I have the below project structure

```
- root
    - main.py
    - test/
        - __init__.py
        - conftest.py
        - test.py
```

In `conftest.py` I have some custom fixtures using `mysql.connector`. Therefore I am importing:

```
import mysql.connector

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')  # maintain connection for all tests
def cnx(database, username, password):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(database=database, user=username, password=password)
    yield cnx
    cnx.close()
```

when I run `test.py` from the terminal in the root directory with the below command:

```
pytest tests/test.py
```

I get the below error:

```
ImportError while loading conftest '/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:5: in <module>
    import mysql.connector
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

**Why is this happening? `mysql` is definitely installed.**

Comment: Try using an alias for your import:
Like so: `import mysql.connector as MODULE_ALIAS`.

PS: don't forget to replace `mysql.connector.connect` with `MODULE_ALIAS.connect`

Comment: If `import mysql` fails, it means that `mysql-connector-python` is not installed. How should running `python -m pytest` help in this case?

Comment: If "it works" because you have simply unpacked MySQL connector into the project root dir, this is surely not the right way of installing third-party packages.

Comment: I assume you are not running this from a python virtual environment? If not, do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running that python on CLI? then try if `import mysql.connector` is working? Another solution is you uninstall the current version of MySQL and try this package instead `pip install mysql-connector-python-rf`

Answer (score -1):

The command to run a test script with `pytest` is not `pytest tests/test.py` but

```
python -m pytest tests/test.py
```

as detailed in the [official docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/usage.html).

Comment: `python -m` only safeguards the version of the python module you are using and is considered best practice. It doesn't affect the command itself (`pytest tests/test.py`)